# How to stream data in 4MB chunks using python (through grpc)

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, grpc-python

I hava a python grpc service that streams large amounts of data to client microservices.

```
service GeoService {
   rpc GetGeoCoordinates(GetRequest) returns (stream Chunk){}
}

message Chunk {
    bytes data_part = 1;
}
```

I can not send more that 4MB of data at once because tcp connection has limits. Here is my code (only relevant part):

```
def GetGeoCoordinates(self, request, context):
    ...
    ...

    dataBytes = geo_pb2.Chunk(data_part=bytes(json.dumps(coordinates["data"]), 'utf-8'))

    yield dataBytes
```

How can I send this data in 4MB chunks?

Also is it a good practice to `json.dumps()` large data then stream? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check if the `result` can be consumed as stream

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I fixed it. Now it is being consumed. Now I need to stream it in 4MB chunks. I would really appreciate if you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

After digging through SO and looking at many answers I finally managed to achieve what I expected:

```
 def GetGeoCoordinates(self, request, context):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 4     # 4 mb
    ...
    ...
    
    # convert data to bytes
    dataBytes = bytes(json.dumps(coordinates["data"]), 'utf-8')

    # stream in 4MB chunks
    index = 0
    while index < len(dataBytes):
        yield geo_pb2.Chunk(
            data_part=dataBytes[index:index+CHUNK_SIZE]
        )
        index += CHUNK_SIZE
```

This answer helped me the most [Chunking in gRPC with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282613/chunking-in-grpc-with-python)